# EF code first automatic foreign key association problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I've got a basic grip of the latest version of EF code first via this tutorial - http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part4-cs but I'm slightly confused about one aspect and wondering if anybody could shed light on it? To explain - there's a class called "Site" which I want to have a field called "HomePageId" which should then map to the "SitePage" object with that Id. Seems simple enough? But when EF creates the Db and the relationships it doesn't seem to understand this. I'm sure it's something I'm doing wrong - here's the code:

```
public class Site
{
    public int SiteId { get; set; }
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
    public string SiteUrlPortion { get; set; }

    // Relationship - SitePages
    public virtual ICollection<SitePage> SitePages { get; set; }

    // Relationship - HomePage
    public int HomePageId { get; set; }
    public virtual SitePage HomePage { get; set; }
}

public class SitePage
{
    public int SitePageId { get; set; }
    public string SitePageTitle { get; set; }
    public string SitePageUrlPortion { get; set; }

    // Relationship - Site
    public int SiteId { get; set; }
    public virtual Site Site { get; set; }       
}
```

The "SitePage" class generates the relationship back to "Site" as you would expect. But what I've got in terms of columns in both tables not only doesn't make sense but the relationship from the code-side of things doesn't work as expected. (Eg when I give the "Site" a "HomePageId" the site's "HomePage" is null.

Obviously there's little out there in terms of documentation because this is still in development, but just wondering if anybody had any ideas? Do I need to start decorating the properties with Attributes? Or am I asking it to understand something that it never will?!

Thanks to all in advance. I'll persevere anyway and post back anything I find obviously.
Rob

Answer (score 1):

try marking your HomePage property with a ForeignKey attribute like this

```
[Foreignkey("HomePageId")]
public virtual SitePage HomePage { get; set; }
```

you could also use the fluent configuration but don't remember that offhand

Comment: Hi Tom - thanks for this suggestion. I did try it but with the same results. Have stuck with a work-around now - two non-key columns "Home page id" and "home page url" - it's not ideal but as they are the only two pieces of data I really need to use it's not a train smash not having the fully-formed "HomePage" object there..

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a limitation in EF. That EF can only handle one relationship between 2 tables.

You have 2 relationships between the tables, to the list of site pages and to the home page.

try removing this line:

```
public virtual SitePage HomePage { get; set; }
```

You still have the homepageid, so in a way this information was redundant.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I know what you're saying but then I'll have to do a further query like "sitePages.Single(p=>p.SitePageid == this.HomePageId)" somewhere - maybe in the HomePage entity class itself which upsets me - I'll try it though!

Comment: And in fact this throws the error - "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.". The answer may be to set up a separate entity called "HomePages". I'll try this now.

Comment: Also check your connection string that MultipleActiveResultSets is set to true.